# You have uncommitted work pending error

Tags: apex, unit-test, api, failing-tests

I am getting a "you have uncommitted work pending" error on a test. Normally this is caused by a DML statement before a callout. That shouldn't be the case here. However, the code runs fine and I am using Test.start and stop appropriately. Im hoping someone can see what I'm missing.

Here's the class:

```
//Scheduler
public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    DoseSpotRetrieval dsr = new DoseSpotRetrieval(); 
    Database.executebatch(dsr, 30);
}

//Loop over accounts (in batches of 30 so calls dont exceed 100)
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    String query = 'SELECT DoseSpot_Id__c FROM Account WHERE DoseSpot_Id__c != null';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

//Handle actual logic
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> accounts){
    String doseSpotSystemUser = Label.DoseSpot_System_User;
    String authToken = DoseSpotCallout.GetAuthToken(doseSpotSystemUser);
    getMetadata(); //This is just SOQL

    List<HealthCloudGA__EhrAllergyIntolerance__c> hcAllergies = new List<HealthCloudGA__EhrAllergyIntolerance__c>();
    List<HealthCloudGA__EhrMedicationPrescription__c> hcMedications = new List<HealthCloudGA__EhrMedicationPrescription__c>();

    //Check setup data
    if(String.isBlank(authToken)) {
        System.debug('Failed to get auth token');
        ErrorUtility.CreateSystemLog('DoseSpotRetrieval','GetAuthToken',null,'Failed to get auth token', true);
    }

    for(Account a : accounts) {
        String patientId = a.DoseSpot_Id__c;

        //Get allergies (Documentation section: 3.1.2), convert to records to hcRecords
        String urlEndAllergies = '/api/patients/' + patientId + '/allergies';
        List<Map<String,Object>> allergies = getDoseSpotData(authToken, urlEndAllergies); //CALLOUT HAPPENS IN THIS METHOD. ITS JUST A CALLOUT, NO DML
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

---

### Here's the test class

```
@TestSetup
static void makeData(){
    SObjectType sobjType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account');
    Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> acctRTs = sobjType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName();

    //Insert patient record
    Account patient = new Account(
        Account_Key__c = '123456-09876',
        FirstName = 'FirstName',
        LastName = 'LastName',
        RecordTypeId = acctRTs.get('Sexual_Health_Patient').getRecordTypeId(),
        DoseSpot_Id__c = '12345'
    );
    insert patient;
}

@isTest
static void testHappyPath() {
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockResponse(0));

    Test.startTest();
        DoseSpotRetrieval dsr = new DoseSpotRetrieval();
        dsr.execute(null);
    Test.stopTest();

    List<HealthCloudGA__EhrAllergyIntolerance__c> allergies = [SELECT HealthCloudGA__Account__c,
                                                                DoseSpot_Id__c 
                                                                FROM HealthCloudGA__EhrAllergyIntolerance__c];

    List<HealthCloudGA__EhrMedicationPrescription__c> meds = [SELECT HealthCloudGA__Account__c,
                                                                DoseSpot_Id__c 
                                                                FROM HealthCloudGA__EhrMedicationPrescription__c];

    System.assertEquals(1, allergies.size());
    System.assertEquals('1', allergies[0].DoseSpot_Id__c);
    System.assert(allergies[0].HealthCloudGA__Account__c != null, 'Account was not populated on allergy');

    System.assertEquals(2, meds.size());
    for(HealthCloudGA__EhrMedicationPrescription__c med : meds) {
        System.assertEquals('1', med.DoseSpot_Id__c);
        System.assert(med.HealthCloudGA__Account__c != null, 'Account was not populated on med');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DML got added in the ErrorUtility method that was getting called. Should have checked if that had been added before posting. Thanks for viewing all

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_dml.htm) states:

> The Test.startTest statement must appear before the Test.setMock statement. Also, the calls to DML operations must not be part of the Test.startTest/Test.stopTest block.

You need to change the order of your calls such that Test.startTest occurs before Test.setMock.

Comment: Ive written dozens of tests this way and it works fine

Comment: @Apexing It sometimes works, yes, but not guaranteed. If you do not follow the directions, you risk having this very issue.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, I appreciate the info. It looks like it was caused by someone adding DML where I didn't expect it. It seems to be working at the top of the method, but I'll definitely keep an eye out for that going forward.

Comment: @Apexing Yeah, it's good to follow directions. I myself had that issue once, learned the hard way. I'm glad you were able to find the source of the problem, though.

Comment: Eh, whatever works...